# Cannot lookup remote EJB3 on JBoss 6.4

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, redhat, ejb-3.0, jboss-eap-6

I need to do an ejb test client for my local ejb , so here's my ejb app details:

This is the bean I want to lookup:

**ServiceFacadeRemote**

```
@Remote
public interface ServiceFacadeRemote {
```

**ServiceFacade**

```
// ServiceFacade implementation class
@Stateless
public class ServiceFacade implements ServiceFacadeRemote,ServiceFacadeLocal{

...
```

Under the "Deployments" section of JBoss 6.4 panel, I can see also the jndi name of the service: *ServiceFacade*

There's also the information of the deployead ear

```
ear name:   ecommerce.ear
ejb name:   ecommerce-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I followed the guide on this link:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

And this is my junit test:

```
static Object lookupRemoteStatelessEjb(Class<?> clazz, Context context) throws NamingException {

    // The app name is the application name of the deployed EJBs. This is typically the ear name
    // without the .ear suffix. However, the application name could be overridden in the application.xml of the
    // EJB deployment on the server.
    // Since we haven't deployed the application as a .ear, the app name for us will be an empty string
    final String appName = "ecommerce";
    // This is the module name of the deployed EJBs on the server. This is typically the jar name of the
    // EJB deployment, without the .jar suffix, but can be overridden via the ejb-jar.xml
    // In this example, we have deployed the EJBs in a jboss-as-ejb-remote-app.jar, so the module name is
    // jboss-as-ejb-remote-app
    final String moduleName = "ecommerce-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT";
    // AS7 allows each deployment to have an (optional) distinct name. We haven't specified a distinct name for
    // our EJB deployment, so this is an empty string
    final String distinctName = "";
    // The EJB name which by default is the simple class name of the bean implementation class
    final String beanName = clazz.getSimpleName();
    // the remote view fully qualified class name
    final String viewClassName = clazz.getName();
    // let's do the lookup
    return context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);
}

@Test
public void readService() {

    final Hashtable<Object,Object> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<Object,Object>();  
    jndiProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    jndiProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
    jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

    Context ctx;

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        ServiceFacadeRemote service = (ServiceFacadeRemote)lookupRemoteStatelessEjb(ServiceFacadeRemote.class, ctx);

        Assert.assertNotNull(service);

        Object output = service.readService(..)

        Assert.assertNotNull(output);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());            
    }

}
```

on line:

```
Object output = service.readService(..)
```

I receive this error:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:ecommerce-backend,...*

The worse thing is by changing *appName* or *moduleName*, the error is the same, so I think that there's a basic error on what I am doing...

Any solution?

**UPDATE**

Changing the call with this:

```
ejb:ecommerce/ecommerce-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT//ServiceFacade!it.infocert.shop.facade.remote.ServiceFacadeRemote
```

but still doesn't work.

However, the call below (without ejb: prefix) seems to work:

```
ecommerce/ecommerce-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ServiceFacade!it.infocert.shop.facade.remote.ServiceFacadeRemote
```

What's the point ???

Answer (score 1):

In `lookupRemoteStatelessEjb()` `beanName` by default is **'the simple class name of the bean implementation'**

Assuming all remote interfaces end on `FacadeRemote` and all stateless classes end on `Facade` you can code

```
    final String beanName = clazz.getSimpleName().replaceAll("Remote$","");
```

Comment: Take a look to the update on the main question please